# Problem with text format while migrating to Jekyll from non-Jekyll blog

Tags: markdown, jekyll, review

UPD1: I am trying to migrate two non-Jekyll blogs into one Jekyll blog. In order to provide that text lines would appear in it as on original pages I use Word processor to search for the line breaks and to add two and more space characters after those breaks: ^l into ^lspacespace. These texts I saved in Unicode or UTF-8 and later pasted them into .md files in _posts folder in Jekyll.

Though when generated these texts have the “Read more” link right after their last sentences, so on the main page these posts are shown with hundreds of lines instead of several lines and a call to read more. I tried to save files in different text editors including Vim.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry @whoiam but your question is completely incomprehensible. Can you explain the problem in a more intelligible way ?